# Query to count number of rows with column value less than the current row's value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like

```
ID      VALUE
-------------
1       0.5
2       0.3
3       1.6
4       5.5
5       0.8
6       0.8
7       0.2
```

I want to write a query to find out number of rows with VALUE less then the current row VALUE. For example, for row ID 5, the total number of rows should 3 (ID 1, 2, 7). So the query result might be like

```
ID      VALUE    LessThanCount
------------------------------
1       0.5      2
2       0.3      1
3       1.6      5
4       5.5      6
5       0.8      3
6       0.8      3
7       0.2      0
```

I am working on the latest MS SQL Server.

Comment: "latest MS SQL Server." won't be correct in a years time, if its 2019 please add that.

Answer (score 5):

I think this can be calculated using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       rank() over (order by value) - 1
from t;
```

`rank()` gives you the number of rows less than the value plus one.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=871794db4f445b4a6eef68193afd3ca7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordon - I tried the query that you have given but its not giving me the expected results.

Comment: @VarunT . . . There was a typo *and* I overthought the answer.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a self (left outer) join.

```
Select A.ID,A.VALUE ,SUM(ISNULL(B.LessThanCount,0)) as LessThanCount
FROM tbl A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT value, count(*) as LessThanCount 
           FROM tbl
           GROUP BY value) B ON B.VALUE < A.VALUE
GROUP BY A.ID,A.VALUE            
ORDER BY A.ID


ID  VALUE   LessThanCount
1   0.5     2
2   0.3     1
3   1.6     5
4   5.5     6
5   0.8     3
6   0.8     3
7   0.2     0
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a RANK:

> One plus the number of rows with a value less than the current value

The question:

*find out number of rows with VALUE less then the current row VALUE.*

The solution:

```
rank() over (order by value) -1
```